# Primary and secondary constraints in core data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Is there such a thing as primary and secondary constraints in core data?
I have a one to many relationship. In the "many" entity, I would like to have a constraint for one attribute. The problem is that the constraint is for all entities that I create and not for the specific one that is related to the "one" entity in the relationship.